# FileLock while copying files

Tags: java

I am trying to edit a json file by 5 different threads and then copy it 5 times, as well, to the same destination path. As you see, there are concurrency problems.

I tried this for the copy method:

```java
public static void copyFile(String originPath, String destinationPath, String file) throws IOException {
    logger.debug("Starting copyFile of" + file);        
    FileChannel channel = null; 
    File lockFile = new File(originPath + file);
    try {
        logger.debug("Comienza el proceso de procesado del json del fichero:" + file);
        channel = extracted(lockFile).getChannel();
        FileLock fileLock = null;
        try {
            fileLock = channel.lock();           
        } catch(OverlappingFileLockException e) {
            logger.error("3 "+e.getMessage());
            Thread.sleep(200);
        }

        FileUtils.copyFile(FileUtils.getFile(originPath + file), FileUtils.getFile(destinationPath + file));
        logger.debug("The copy of " + file + " ends.");
        fileLock.release();
        channel.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        logger.error("Failing to copy "+file " to  " + destinationPath + e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

I'm getting nulls and `IOException`s. 
All I want is that when a file is processed the other threads just wait for it in a queue, one after each other.

Comment: What exceptions do you get exactly (with message) and on what lines?

Comment: Do you really need multiple threads? If so, you'll need to have `synchroized` access to the file. Check [Oracle's tutorial on multithreading](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/).

Comment: "_File locks are held on behalf of the entire Java virtual machine. They are not suitable for controlling access to a file by multiple threads within the same virtual machine_." – [`FileLock`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/channels/FileLock.html).

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly your problem is when one of your threads tries to copy one file, other threads wait in a queue and then start their work one by one.

you can achieve this by code below

```
public class FileLock {
    static Semaphore semaphore = new Semaphore(1);

    public static void copyFile(String originPath, String destinationPath, String file) throws IOException {
        try {
            semaphore.acquire();
            logger.debug("Comienza el proceso de procesado del json del fichero:" + file);
            FileUtils.copyFile(FileUtils.getFile(originPath + file), FileUtils.getFile(destinationPath + file));
            logger.debug("The copy of " + file + " ends.");
        } catch (IOException | InterruptedException e) {
            logger.error("Failing to copy " + file" to  " + destinationPath + e.getMessage());
        } finally {
            semaphore.release();
        }
    }
}
```